# Почему стоит запятая перед тире («Грамота.ру»)?

Tags: запятая-перед-тире

Вот, собственно, сам вопрос: «Здравствуйте. Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении? "Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари — тролли, химеры, порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные феи и блуждающие огоньки, но даже самые маленькие и глупые альтмеры знали, как избегать их".

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Пояснительный оборот тролли, химеры нужно выделить тире с двух сторон: Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари — тролли, химеры, — порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные феи и блуждающие огоньки... В остальном всё верно».

Почему в предложении: *Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари — тролли, химеры, — порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные феи и блуждающие огоньки...* — «Грамота» ставит запятую перед тире?

Comment: Максим, очень хороший вопрос, голос от меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему в предложении: *Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные
> твари — тролли, химеры, — порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные
> феи и блуждающие огоньки*... — «Грамота» ставит запятую перед тире?

Запятая здесь разделяет части сложного **бессоюзного** предложения:

***Водились твари, встречались феи и огоньки…***